# Automatic condensing of whitespace in HTML

Tags: php, regex

One of the things that has occurred to me more recently is that if you add up all of the bandwidth that is taken up by thousands of users downloading the newlines and tabs used to make HTML source code readable... that's a LOT of wasted bandwidth.

So I wanted to add some code that would condense whitespace on-the-fly before sending it to the browser.

I then very quickly realised that sometimes, whitespace is significant. For example, in `<textarea>`s or `<pre>` tags.

After double-checking, I've come to the firm conclusion that there is absolutely no use of `white-space` CSS values such as `pre-wrap` that would make whitespace significant, except in the case of a custom `<rainbow>` tag (which is parsed by JavaScript for colour codes and things - long story XD)

So with that in mind, I wanted to condense whitespace that is not contained in a `<textarea>`, `<pre>` or `<rainbow>`. I accomplished this with `DOMDocument` and a `DOMXPath`, in other words, "doing it right". But then I learned about regex verbs, and replaced my code with this:

```
// uber hax with regex
$str = trim(preg_replace("(<(textarea|rainbow|pre).*?</\\1>(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+)s"," ",$str));
```

It, um... well, it works, or at least it seems to from what I can tell. But I wanted to post here so I can ask, have I missed anything important? Or is it really this simple?

Comment: How about <blockquote> tag?

Comment: @andrew [doesn't seem to have significant whitespace by default](http://jsfiddle.net/8v2zt/)

Comment: i see. Ok then.

Comment: I'd still use gzip compression, but this regexp looks interesting.

Comment: The only thing I can see that could be improved at the moment is making it case insensitive, currently it doesn't match <TEXTAREA></TEXTAREA>

Comment: Here you go: `$str = trim(preg_replace("(<(textarea|rainbow|pre).*?</\\1>(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+)si"," ",$str));`

Comment: @TravisWeston Ah, good point. I'm just so used to having HTML lowercase that it completely slipped my mind that there was an alternative XD

Comment: I think we've all been there.

Comment: As for this, I really like the idea. It could be incorporated into an MVC as an option to minify automatically. I'd love to see that, actually.

Comment: @TravisWeston That might be nice, but remember I built this code on certain assumptions, most notably that I have very strict definitions of when whitespace is meaningful. Now, a framework that can actually parse CSS to determine if whitespace is meaningful might be possible, but it wouldn't be nearly as simple as this code XD

Comment: Of course, I was less thinking specifically about this code, and more the concept of automatic whitespace minimization.

Answer (score 3):

- I don't see much reason to use `(*F)` instead of the somewhat more understandable `(*FAIL)`.
- Consider using single-quoted (`'`) strings for regular expressions to avoid `\\1`.
- There's a big assumption here that the HTML will be well-formed. I assume <sup><sub>(ha!)</sub></sup> that this is okay.
- Whitespace is significant in `<input>` tags.

Comment: Ooh, that last point... You're right, and especially the `value` attribute. Should be simple enough to add, in theory. Thanks for the feedback!